# Unity 5.2.1 Build crash on Application.Quit(); with Windows Touch

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am upgrading my Unity 4 project to Unity 5.2.1. I have used Application.Quit(); to close the app on a button click. This worked fine earlier(Unity 4) with Mouse and Touch both and now (Unity 5.2) also works fine with mouse click. But if I click the button using Touch (on Windows 8 or Windows 7 Touch screens) the app crashes.

Then I tested by creating a new Unity project and added the cs file with the below code to the main camera. When I click this button with Touch it crashes. But doesn't crash with the mouse click. Is this a bug in Unity 5.2.1? How can I fix this issue?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

public Texture btnTexture;

void OnGUI()
{
    if (!btnTexture)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Please assign a texture on the inspector");
        return;
    }
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 10, 50, 50), btnTexture))
    {
        Debug.LogError("Clicked the button with an image");
        Application.Quit();
    }

    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 70, 50, 30), "Click"))
        Debug.LogError("Clicked the button with text");

    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT:]
This solved the problem:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
// instead of
// Application.Quit();
```

Have you tried to call **Application.Quit** from outside of the OnGUI method?
Like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 10, 50, 50), "Exit"))
        {
            StartCoroutine(Quit());
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerator Quit()
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Denis. Now I tried your code and still the same happens when I use the Touch.

Comment: One more thing that you could try is this:
`System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();`
instead of `Application.Quit();`
I don't know if it works on Windows, but it did solve some crashes with an old version of Unity on Android for me.

Comment: Thanks Denis. That seems to solve the Crashing issue. But will there be any side effects in using the GetCurrentProcess().Kill()?

Comment: Make some tests and see if Windows shows any error messages. I have used this solution for some of my games on Android and never got a complaint.

Comment: Use `if(!Application.isEditor) { System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill(); }`, otherwise it'll crash the player/Unity too! While this solution works, it's a "hard quit" and shouldn't be used if `Application.Quit()` works. Unfortunately the suggested `IEnumerator` version still makes my app freeze, so I have no choice. :/

Answer (score 0):

if (Input.GetKey("escape"))
            Application.Quit();

Comment: you can use this not only for windows but also for android build too