# Unity app build freezes on calling "Application.Quit()"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, exit

My Unity 2017.3 app has two main scenes:

1. A simpl-ish "Main Menu" scene - calling `Application.Quit()` on a button press there closes the app, as expected.
2. The main "Game" scene - calling `Application.Quit()` within its pause menu (a panel that uses `Time.timeScale = 0f` on open and `Time.timeScale = 1f` on close) causes the app to freeze. 5 seconds later I get the grey-ish overlay and Windows' blue, turning circle and a little bit later the "myapp.exe has stopped working" popup appears.

This only happens with a built version of my app ("PC, Mac & Linux Standalone", started via the exe), as `Application.Quit()` doesn't do anything in Unity's player.

There's a lot going on in the main scene but I'm (trying to) stop all the `InvokeRepeating`s, `Thread`s and `Coroutine`s I'm using:

```
public void ExitApp() {
    Time.timeScale = 1f;

    if(stalker!=null) {
        stalker.GetComponent<Stalker>().enabled = false; //InvokeRepeating script attached to a GO
        stalker.SetActive(false);
    }

    if(loadGOThread!=null) {
        keepThreadStuffRunning = false; //used in the thread
        loadGOThread.Abort();
    }

    if(co2!=null) { StopCoroutine(co2); } //Two coroutines
    if(co1!=null) { StopCoroutine(co1); } //co1 starts co2

    myPlayer.GetComponent<PlayerController>().enabled = false;
    myPlayer.GetComponent<InputManagerGame>().enabled = false;

    Application.Quit();
}
```

I tried to use a coroutine as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34083873/2016165):

```
public void ExitApp() {
    StartCoroutine(QuitApp());
}

public IEnumerator QuitApp() {
    //Stopping everything here
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    Application.Quit();
}
```

The app still freezes.

I then replaced `Application.Quit()` with (as suggested [here](http://answers.unity.com/comments/748372/view.html)):

```
if (!Application.isEditor) { System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill(); }
```

This worked of course but it seems more "cut throat"-y than a proper solution. Is there anything I'm missing, anything else I have to do before I can call `Application.Quit()`?

I call `Quit()` and `Dispose()` on all the `StreamReader`s I use, so those shouldn't "leak". The only things left are a bunch of `GameObject`s in memory (that are displayed at the time of quitting the app) and two empty/invisible "DontDestroyOnLoad" GameObjects that I get from the "Main Menu" scene - one of those has the script I'm calling all of this from attached to it, so I can't just destroy it (can I?).

Comment: suggestions: (1) when it is freezed, break in the debugger and have a look at the execution call stacks of all threads to figure out what it is waiting for/blocking, (2) does the program output debug pane say anything useful?

Comment: (1) I'm exporting as a development build but sorry, how do I open the debugger for it? (2) I know that crashes/exceptions write stuff to some kind of console that pops up in development builds (is that the pane you're talking about?) but that's not happening in this case. The app simply freezes when I click on the "Exit" button (it's still got the "pressed" color then) but there aren't any errors in said console and also no log files in the same folder the exe is in.

Comment: you should be able to attach a debugger to the running sandbox: Debug > Attach Unity Debugger, if you're using VS.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! Can I also somehow do this for an exported version of the app? `Application.Quit()` (or even the `System....` version) doesn't do anything if I call it in Unity's player. My other code still runs, so of course closing the pause menu won't really let you continue using my app because I stop all the important bits... but because Unity doesn't actually close the app, I can't know for sure if closing the app in the player still runs the same background processes/clean-ups as closing the actual exported app would (should).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Can you post an answer to this question? I'm also struggling with this...

Comment: @Jon Sorry, I haven't worked on the app in a while, so I'm not absolutely sure but I don't think I found a solution.